# Circumference of the ellipse, elliptic integrals, and WolframAlpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha, elliptic-integrals

The arc length of a graph of a function $f(x)$ is

$$\mathcal{l} = \int_a^b \sqrt {1 + f'(x)^2} dx$$

If you choose $f$ to be a parametrization of the ellipse with $a=1, b=\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-x^2}$, the arc length of the graph of this function is

$$\mathcal{l} = \int_0^1 \sqrt\frac{1-\frac{3x^2}{4} }{1-x^2}dx$$

If you enter `int_0^1 sqrt((1-(3x^2)/4)/(1-x^2))dx` at wolframalpha.com you will get the result:

[image]

What [I would have expected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference) here as the argument of $E$ (the complete elliptic integral of the second kind) was the eccentricity $e = \sqrt{1-(b/a)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}$ but it's $e^2$.

> Is this a Wolframalpha bug or did I make or understand something wrong?

Comment: Show exactly how you manipulated the upper and lower bounds of integration to get your integral

Comment: Is it wrong the way I did it: "int_0^1..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram has an unconventional definition of the elliptic integrals. If you look at [the manual](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EllipticE.html?q=EllipticE&lang=en) you see that the argument of `EllipticE` is $m$ which is related to the [usual argument](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html) $k$ of $E(k)$ via $m=k^2$.

Comment: It's not "unconventional"; some people prefer the modulus, and some people prefer the parameter...